# How can we resolve the Google web driver issue in Selenium 3.141.0 and python 2.7

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium -3.141.0
python-2.7
google web driver--74.0.3729.6
google web browser--74.0.3729.169

**using below code to access google.com**

"from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, 
executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

browser.get('http://www.google.com/')"

**getting below issue**

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Linux 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64)

Comment: Please have a careful read through [ask].

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try executing `/usr/bin/google-chrome` command in terminal - if it will not be successful - you will not be able to proceed. You can check status code using [`$?` variable](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command) - it should be equal to `0`
2. It might be the case there is no [DISPLAY](https://support.objectplanet.com/esupport/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=17) variable defined hence Chrome cannot launch properly. Make sure to have this variable defined and pointing to either real or [virtual display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb).
3. There is a possibility to [run Chrome in headless mode](https://medium.com/@pyzzled/running-headless-chrome-with-selenium-in-python-3f42d1f5ff1d), add the next lines to your script:

   ```
   chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
   ```

   You can see [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python) reference project for example configuration/initialisation
4. Make sure that [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and Chrome versions are matching

Comment: I have tried above mentioned solution but no use. please help me